# Rabbitmq reaching file descriptor limit causes clients to hang indefinitely

Tags: python, rabbitmq, file-descriptor, pika, kombu

After experiencing an issue where my rabbitmq server reached its file descriptor limit and ceased to accept any new connections, I noticed that my clients consuming from queues behaved in a ***very*** undesirable way.

When trying to open their connections they hung indefinitely without throwing any errors..

I'm currently using the Kombu library, and upon recreating the issue, no amount of tweaking the connection parameters would prevent the connection instantiation from blocking indefinitely. The timeout doesn't trigger, and enabling heartbeat doesn't help either. Looking at `strace` I see that it opens a connection to the rabbitmq server and then waits for data forever.

I've also just tried using the Pika library and have experienced the same issue. The difference being that `strace` shows the connection being polled. The connection instantiation still blocks indefinitely though.

Is there something I'm missing? What is the correct way to open connections to your rabbitmq server without them hanging silently forever when something goes wrong?

### Edit:

Here's some code, it's pretty much hello world..

### Pika:

```
import pika
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(
               'localhost', socket_timeout=2, heartbeat_interval=1))
channel = connection.channel()  # Hangs indefinitely
```

### Kombu:

```
import kombu
connection = kombu.Connection('amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672//')
connection.connect()  # Hangs indefinitely
```

Comment: Can you share some code? It's little bit unclear what you trying to solve. Connection problem or consuming messages from the queue?

Comment: Instantiating a new connection hangs. There may also be similar problems with consuming from existing connections, but instantiation of new connections is definitely problematic. Adding the client code now.

Comment: Can you add logging and post the output: 
```
fmt = logging.Formatter('[%(levelname)s] %(message)s')
handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
handler.setFormatter(fmt)

pika_log = logging.getLogger('pika')
pika_log.addHandler(handler)
pika_log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)```

Comment: Will see if that produces anything interesting, cheers.

Comment: This is most likely a socket issue. The pika developer gmr implemented a client-side heartbeat check in his new library to counter these type of issues.
https://github.com/gmr/rabbitpy